# time complexity for a sorting technique for stacks?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, stack, big-o, time-complexity

Say I have the following pseudo code:

```
while A is not empty and stack top of A is less than x:
    pop A and push the returned value onto B
push x onto A
while B is not empty:
    pop B and push the returned valued onto A
```

> say stacks A and B are initially empty. Insert n numbers with a new number x each time using the above algorithm, what would be worst time complexity.

I was able to get that this algorithm would sort the inserting numbers with length **n** from smallest(top) to largest(bottom), and the best case would be **n** when the numbers inserted are already sorted, from largest to smallest. But I don't get how the worst case can be **O(n^2)**.

Comment: From Where does x come from.

Comment: sorry I left out some details. `x` is the number inserted each time.

Comment: This is a clumsy (maybe a formalized form of) Insertion Sort. And that is well known to be O(n^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've realized, this algorithm uses 2 stacks to sort a collection of items.

At each step, it pops items from A and pushes then into B till the right place is found. Then it pops from B and pushes back to A.

This means that at step *n*, there's a maximum of *2*(n-1)+1* operations.

If the initial collection is reverse-sorted, this will happen with each insertion, making the complexity **O(N<sup>2</sup>)**.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting n elements without sorting would be o(n). As each sort is o(n), the total is O(n^2).
Worst case: numbers are presented in the reversed order.

Answer (score 0):

For each insertion the best case scenario is when StackTop[A]>x, then it would just push x into A and B would empty. So time complexity is o(1) for each insertion in best case. So for n elements o(n)

Now suppose elements are inserted in increasing order then each insertion would cause the Stack A to be emptied and put in B.
After this insert x in to A and then put stack B elements into A popping and pushing one by one. This requires o(n) for each insertion. so for n insertion o(n^2).

Answer (score 0):

In worst case:
lets take an example of input `{1,2,3,4}`
**step1**:`(x=1)`
 
initially A,B are empty. so by the algorithm `A{1}`, `B{}`.
**step2**:`(x=2)`
by algorithm `B={1}`, `A ={2}` and then `A={1,2}` `B={}`.
**step3**:`(x=3)`
by algorithm initially `B={2,1}` `A={3}` and then `A={3,2,1}` `B={}`.
**step4**:`(x=4)`
by algorithm initially `B={1,2,3}` `A={4}` and then `A={4,3,2,1}` `B={}` 
cost for each step is `(2*(n-1))` where `n` is size of input.
so if we sum up Worst case Time complexity is **O(n^2)**